# access file path outside application directory in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I need to access file (videos) stored somewhere in a server that is accessible via intranet.

I am having trouble fetching and loading the file path.

The file is situated in the same server that is hosting the application though.

Here's what I tried:

```
<video id="video_player_frame" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="595" data-setup="{}">
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">

  <!-- <source src="\\192.168.11.32\www\GBD-Videos\testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->

  <p class="vjs-no-js">Javascript is disabled.</p>
</video>
```

The one with the public address is working fine (obviously).

But the file path `\\192.168.11.32\www\GBD...` is not working.

How can I access that file and render it?

Comment: if you type that path directly into the browser, does the video load? you may need to adjust it so it's correct for absolute/relative reference from the root page

Comment: yes. it does.. the path works that way